# Hierarchy relationship SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Anyone can help me to come out a query for below ? The objective is to transform entity as shown in expected output.

```
Child   Parent  Name
0001    0001    HQ
0100    0001    HQ Accounting Dept
0200    0001    HQ Marketing Dept
0300    0001    HQ HR Dept
0101    0100    Branch North 111 
0102    0100    Branch North 112
0201    0200    Branch North 113
0301    0300    Branch North 114
8900    0300    Branch North 115
0387    8900    Sub Branch North 115

Expected output
----------------
Level1   Level2   Level3   Level4  Name
0001     0100     0101     N/A     Branch North 111
0001     0100     0102     N/A     Branch North 112
0001     0200     0201     N/A     Branch North 113
0001     0300     0301     N/A     Branch North 114
0001     0300     8900     0387    Sub Branch North 115
```

I've tried to query it but answer is not really correct

```
with cte as
(select Child,Parent from cmbc_entity
 where Parent = '0001'),
 cte2 as
 (select A.Parent as Level1, B.Child as Level2, C.Child as Level3, C.Name
 from cmbc_entity B inner join cte A on A.Child = B.Parent inner join cmbc_entity C on B.Child   =     C.Parent
 where B.Child != '0001')
 select * from cte2
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far ? you're not likely to get people to help you if they think you are too lazy to even attempt something yourself.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Should be a few self left joins, and a coalesce for the Name.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: A very good question but poorly asked :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server

Comment: In your table, is Child a unique id for each row?  For example, is 'Branch North 111' the only record that could have Child = '0101'?

Comment: Can you explain in English what you are trying to achieve?  For example, Why are the 'HQ...' records not included in the results?  Are you only looking for Level3 and Level4 records?

Comment: Child is a unique id for each row

Comment: I'm looking up to level 4 records

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening Hierarchy series using SQL Server CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055141/flattening-hierarchy-series-using-sql-server-cte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation with pulling the data set this way is that you will of course never be able to hit more than 4 levels. Dynamic columns is a major pain to try and implement.

You could probably set up a recursive ID, but your column would be more like Self, Parent, Grandparent, grandgrandparent, name which could get a little weird quickly.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
  DeptID INT,
  ParentID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO Department
VALUES
  (1,1,'HQ'),
  (100,1,'HQ Accounting Dept'),
  (200,1,'HQ Marketing Dept'),
  (300,1,'HQ HR Dept'),
  (101,100,'Branch North 111'),
  (102,100,'Branch North 112'),
  (201,200,'Branch North 113'),
  (301,300,'Branch North 114'),
  (8900,300,'Branch North 115'),
  (387,8900,'Sub Branch North 115');

;WITH cte_Level1 AS (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DeptID) [Level1],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')  [Level2],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')  [Level3],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')  [Level4],
        Name
    FROM Department
    WHERE DeptID = ParentID
), cte_Level2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte_Level1 UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level1) [Level1],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), D.DeptID) [Level2],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')    [Level3],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')    [Level4],
    D.Name
    FROM Department D
    INNER JOIN cte_Level1 A ON A.Level1 = D.ParentID
    WHERE D.DeptID <> D.ParentID
), cte_Level3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte_Level2 UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level1) [Level1],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level2) [Level2],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), D.DeptID) [Level3],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'N/A')    [Level4],
        D.Name
    FROM Department D
    INNER JOIN cte_Level2 A ON A.Level2 = D.ParentID
        AND A.Level2 <> 'N/A'
    WHERE D.DeptID <> D.ParentID
), cte_Level4 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte_Level3 UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level1) [Level1],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level2) [Level2],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), A.Level3) [Level3],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), D.DeptID)    [Level4],
        D.Name
    FROM Department D
    INNER JOIN cte_Level3 A ON A.Level3 = D.ParentID
        AND A.Level3 <> 'N/A'
    WHERE D.DeptID <> D.ParentID
)

SELECT * FROM cte_Level4
```

Comment: it was comprehensive to me, thank you. Is it possible to make query more flexible ? because in the future the level could be more than > 4

Comment: Unfortunately not, I added some text to the answer describing the issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this elegant approach to flatten your hierarchy, using recursive CTE's. 
Here's a solution to a similar question 
[Stack Overflow: Flattening Hierarchy series using SQL Server CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055141/flattening-hierarchy-series-using-sql-server-cte)

Answer (score 0):

Test my script with other sample data.Though i am myself not much satisfied because i hate using distinct.
I will try to modify and update here for following reason :-

1. Why I have to use distinct?
2. why i am using b.level1 is not null in my final query .

At the same time i am quite sure about other thing .Like my script is very short.Also it is easy to convert to dynamic sql because of levelid.

**are you sure about your output ?**

```
Declare @t table (Child varchar(10),  Parent  varchar(10),  Name varchar(50))

insert into @t
select '0001','0001','HQ' union all
select'0100','0001','HQ Accounting Dept' union all
select'0200','0001','HQ Marketing Dept' union all
select'0300','0001','HQ HR Dept' union all
select'0101','0100','Branch North 111' union all
select'0102','0100','Branch North 112'union all
select'0201','0200','Branch North 113'union all
select'0301','0300','Branch North 114'union all
select'8900','0300','Branch North 115'union all
select '0387','8900','Sub Branch North 115'
--select * from @t
;with CTE as
(
select child,parent,name,case when parent=child then 1 else 0 end level1 from @t a 
)
,cte2 as
(
select * from cte where level1=1
union all
select a.Child,a.Parent,a.Name,b.level1+1  from @t a inner join cte2 b on a.parent=b.child and a.child<>b.child
)
select distinct
isnull(b.child,'N/A') Level1
,isnull(c.child,'N/A')  Level2
,isnull(d.child,'N/A') Level3
,isnull(e.child,'N/A') Level4
,case when e.child is null then d.name
      when d.child is null then c.name
      when c.child is null then b.name
      when b.child is null then a.name else e.Name end Name
from cte2 a
left join cte2 b on  a.parent=b.child  and b.level1=1
left join cte2 c on  b.child=c.parent  and c.level1=2
left join cte2 d on  c.Child=d.Parent  and d.level1=3
left join cte2 e on  d.Child=e.Parent  and e.level1=4
where b.level1 is not null
```